# Minimizing size of signed message with discrete-log scheme

Tags: signature, discrete-logarithm, message-recovery

**How can we sign a small message with a discrete-log scheme so as to minimize the size of the whole signed message?**

---

Detailed objectives, notation:

1. It is of paramount importance to minimize the total bit size $c$ of the cryptogram $C$ carrying the whole signed message $M$, e.g. because $C$ will be keyed-in (appropriately transformed to characters). $M$ is an arbitrary bitstring of $m$ bits, for some parameter $m$ with $32\le m\le256$.
2. We restrict to asymmetric signature algorithms loosely based on the discrete logarithm problem in some group (we note $q$ its order), e.g. because some directive only allows that or integer factorization which is inappropriate given 1; schemes using pairing-based cryptography are out. We have unrestricted choice of symmetric primitives likes hashes.
3. It must be arguable that a competent adversary using public knowledge and classical computers is unlikely to exhibit a forged signature (in a chosen-messages setup) with $2^w$ work for some parameter $w\approx80$, in a sense such that $w=67$ represents the work reported for the factorization of RSA-768:

   > <sup>Our computation required more than 10<sup>20</sup> operations. With the equivalent of almost 2000 years of computing on a single core 2.2GHz AMD Opteron, on the order of 2<sup>67</sup> instructions were carried out.</sup>
4. Each signature generation and verification must be feasible with $2^{32}$ work, but performance is otherwise non-critical, as well as key size (public and private).

Questions:

- Are there better schemes than DSA and ECDSA variants with message recovery (see bibliography in this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40270/555)), and which one(s) can we choose? What is the corresponding maximum capacity (that is, the largest $m$ such that we have full message recovery, and larger messages start to require increasing $c$)?
- Are we better using group $\mathbb Z_p^*$ with $q$ a prime factor of $p-1$ as in plain DSA, or an Elliptic-Curve group, or..?
- What parameters is it reasonable to use (for DSA variants: size of $p$ and $q$; for ECDSA variants: curve..), and what's the $c$ achieved?

Update: I now realize that the Schnorr signature scheme of 1989 yields $c=m+3w$-bit (for at most $2^{w/2}$ signatures). That's a candidate (related [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48528/555)).

---

Extras:

- In (EC)DSA, we can trim a few bits from $C$ (reducing $c$ by $z_s+z_v$), by having the signer iterate signing until $z_s$ prescribed bits are (say) all set; and the verifier iterates verification with incremental values of $z_v$ other prescribed bits, until finding a signature that verifies. We can increase $z_s$ and $z_v$ within the limits set by requirement 4, with almost no reduction of security. Can we better leverage that leeway? E.g. by increasing $p$ in DSA, or somewhat using an [entropy-stretching KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (PBKDF2, Argon2..)? [for the DSA aspect of that, see this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48438/555)]
- Does things appreciably change, allowing lower $c$, if we relax security requirement 3 to distinguish between total breaks that allow the adversary to recover the private key or otherwise sign any $M$ at low cost, and those that would be unprofitable to an adversary if each forgery requires $2^{w'}$ work with $w'\approx w-16$?

Comment: Don't you want to squeeze to the minimum? Joking aside, I think that the number of sub-questions is a bit on the large side. Numbering them may help somewhat, but asking separate questions would be preferred (maybe after getting an answer here). Nevertheless, interesting question - hope you get an answer this time around :)

Answer (score 2):

This only answers part of the question, but here goes:

Classical Schnorr signatures start (in my notation, which I think will be helpful here) with a field $\mathbb F$, a linear map $f: \mathcal W \to \mathcal V$ over $\mathbb F$-vector spaces and a hash $H$ with codomain in $\mathbb F$. For simplicity let's take $\mathcal W = \mathbb F$. I'll use capital letters for elements of $\mathcal V$ and small ones for field elements. Intuitively, elements of $\mathcal V$ take more bits to represent than field elements.

The finite field implementation is to take primes $p, q = (p-1)/2$ and set $\mathbb F = \mathbb Z_q$,  $\mathcal V$ is an order-$q$ subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ generated by some $g$, vector addition is $v \oplus w := v \cdot w \pmod{p}$ and scalar multiplication (that makes the whole thing into a vector space) is $(x, V) \mapsto V^x \pmod{p}$. The linear function is $f(x) := g^x \pmod{p}$ for vanilla Schnorr.

For elliptic curve implementations (DSA, ECDSA, EdDSA) $\mathbb F$ is a finite field and $\mathcal V$ is a group defined over an appropriate elliptic curve, with point addition serving as vector addition and scalar multiplication of $x$ with $V$ is point-adding $V$ to itself $x$ times.

In both cases,

- A keypair is a pair $(x, Y = f(x)) \in \mathbb F \times \mathcal V$.
- To sign $M$ (which can be any bitstring), you pick a random $r \in \mathbb F$, set $A = f(r)$, $c = H(Y, A, M)$ and $s = r + cx$.
- The "$4w$" version of the signature is $(A, s) \in \mathcal V \times \mathbb F$ whereas the "hash compressed" or "$3w$" version is $(c, s) \in \mathbb F \times \mathbb F$, since field elements are smaller than $\mathcal V$ elements.
- The verification equations in both cases are $c = H(Y, A, M)$ and $f(s) = A + c \cdot Y$.

Which brings me to two recommendations.

1. In the hash-compressed version, the signature consists only of field elements, so it should not matter for signature size if you choose a finite-field or EC implementation: the size of keys (field elements) is the same for both at the same security level on keylength.com. What EC buys you is shorter $\mathcal V$ elements, which is irrelevant here. I'd personally go with Ed25519 just because I like it.
2. The probability of forging a proof is commonly given as $1/|\mathbb F|$ but really it's the inverse of the size of the codomain of the hash. While $s$ has to be a full field element, you can truncate the hash value $c$ to any smaller number $k$ of bits as long as you're happy with a lower soundness factor of $2^{-k}$.

EDIT: You can also do the $z_s + z_v$ bits thing here of course, but it seems like it doesn't buy you much. I thought for a bit how I'd prove the security of the version where the verifier iterates over $z_v$ "omitted" bits and the best I could come up with is a union bound, so by omitting $z_v$ bits you lose $z_v$ bits of security and force the verifier to do $2^{z_v}$ times the work, in exchange for transmitting $z_v$ fewer bits. Shortening the hash output by $z$ bits also loses you $z$ bits of security, but doesn't cause anyone more work.
(If you can prove that you can fix or omit some bits *without* losing that many bits of security, then of course this option becomes attractive again.)